# InDesign's Glyph pane lists horizonal lines as bullets?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, typography

As I know, there is such thing as *dinkus* that is used to demark section breaks.

[image]

A dinkus can be one or three asterisk, a fleuron, or a horizontal line.

When I open InDesign's Glyph pane, there is a character that looks exactly as a fancy horizonal line, although it is actually listed as a bullet (and is copied as •), hence my confusion.

[image]

Why is it listed as a bullet? Is it professional to use this character as a section break, that is, as a horizontal line, as shown in my example, or we should use it only as a bullet, like bullets in shopping and TODO lists?

Comment: If it’s copied as a bullet, that probably just means whoever made the font you’re using put this squiggly line in the glyph whose code is that of the bullet’s – similar to how the font Symbol has Greek letters instead of Latin in the regular Latin code slots (so typing ‘Zeus’ you’ll have ‘Ζεθσ’ on the page). That doesn’t have anything to do with whether you should use it as a fleuron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you like how it looks just use it.**

Who even says you can't use an *ordinary* bullet character as dinkus if it fits your design? Or a simple symbol you've drawn yourself? Or a symbol from another font?

The names of the characters can of course help you to use different symbols correctly, but nobody will ever reward you for using a correct symbol that looks wrong or punish you for using a wrong symbol that looks correct.

In the end the designer is responsible for making things look good and must do whatever it takes to accomplish that.